# Infinite Swipe functionality

Tags: android, swipe

Guys, I have two questions implementing this functionality

1- I implemented swipe using [Card Stack View](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView#callbacks), Is there something better?

2- How to implement infinite swipe, like what in video, in the most efficient way?

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PxvZeqFjFjWg_VGgMEDnqMwbzvpS6LBI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share video link again, as it show access denied

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PxvZeqFjFjWg_VGgMEDnqMwbzvpS6LBI/view?usp=sharing